# Sub query not working as expected trying to order by then group by, MySQL 5.5 vs 5.7

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.7

I do not know/understand DB's as well as I would like. I'm trying to `ORDER BY` and then `GROUP BY` so that I get the first record from each group of results in the database.

```
-- Example table (just an example. real table may contain hundreds of rows where field 2 is a duplicate but field 3 and 4 are different.)

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `docs` (
  `field1` int(6) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `field2` int(6) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `field3` int(6) NOT NULL,
  `field4` int(6) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`field1`)
) DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
INSERT INTO `docs` (`field1`, `field2`, `field3`, `field4`) VALUES
  ('27908', '82', '1', '17'),
  ('27907', '82', '1', '50'),
  ('402', '25', '1', '90'),
  ('312', '25', '10', '8');
```

If I `ORDER BY` the results are as expected. Note it works without sub-query.  I'm just breaking apart my original query:

```
SELECT * FROM 
(
SELECT * FROM docs
ORDER BY field2, field1 DESC
)
```

Result ([formmated with table generator](https://ozh.github.io/ascii-tables/)):

```
+--------+--------+--------+--------+
| field1 | field2 | field3 | field4 |
+--------+--------+--------+--------+
|    402 |     25 |      1 |     90 |
|    312 |     25 |     10 |      8 |
|  27908 |     82 |      1 |     17 |
|  27907 |     82 |      1 |     50 |
+--------+--------+--------+--------+
```

The `ORDER BY` then `GROUP BY` works as expected in MySQL `v5.5`:

```
SELECT * FROM 
(
SELECT * FROM docs
ORDER BY field2, field1 DESC
) temp
GROUP BY field2
```

Result:

```
+--------+--------+--------+--------+
| field1 | field2 | field3 | field4 |
+--------+--------+--------+--------+
|    402 |     25 |      1 |     90 |
|  27908 |     82 |      1 |     17 |
+--------+--------+--------+--------+
```

But it no longer works in `v5.7` and results in error:

`Query Error: Error: ER_WRONG_FIELD_WITH_GROUP: Expression #1 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column 'temp.field1' which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by`

I don't understand how to fix when using a sub-query or another way to write the query that works in `v5.7`. How can this query be changed to work in MySQL `v5.7`?

Comment: Check this variable in your 5.5 and 5.7 environments: `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE "sql_mode"`. I think you will find "ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY" in 5.7. You can change it if you want so it works like 5.5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct, this was different in earlier versions

> ...However, in MySQL prior to version 5.7 the default behaviour has been
>   more forgiving because it will not complain and then arbitrarily
>   choose any value! It also has an ANY_VALUE() function that could be
>   used as another solution to this question if you really needed the
>   same behaviour as before...

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34115174/error-related-to-only-full-group-by-when-executing-a-query-in-mysql)

But this change is a **good** thing, as the error used to be silenced. 
I would recommend changing the query to get the results you want. I believe you want the one where field1 is the largest.

`Field1` is the primary key, so you could possibly do something like the following

```
SELECT docs.field1,docs.field2,docs.field3,docs.field4
FROM 
(
SELECT max(field1) as field1 ,field2 FROM docs
GROUP BY field2
) temp
INNER JOIN docs
on temp.field1 = docs.field1 
ORDER BY field2, field1 desc;
```

[DBFiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/jU71jLPa39BfZgzanCiZuq/0)

The other way around this are to either disable the functionality or use `ANY_VALUE()` but I would advise against that.

`ANY_VALUE()` can give an inconsistent resultset, an example could be the number 50 instead of the expected 17 as `field4` where the `field1` column = 27908.

[DBFiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/gEkJdwePhNfhpUN2PfTZXN/0)